# What causes the Mouse Pointer to not be lined up with the selection on a combobox or listview

Tags: listview, pointers, uwp, combobox

The best way to describe this is with a picture so here it is. you can see that the mouse pointer does not line up with the item it is selecting on the combobox. I've seen this happen on listviews also. What causes this and how do I fix it. It happens in UWP Apps
[image]

Comment: attach a picture of the state before clicking the combobox

Comment: Muzib the pointer is perfectly accurate outside of the combobox or listview. Also, I have determined that the pointer is also accurate in the combobox and listview if the window is full screen. it only does this when the window is resized smaller. The page is also inside of a viewbox control. which may be causing the issue

Comment: Hello, Do you want the selected item to appear at the position of the mouse when you open the ComboBox?

Comment: Yes Richard that would be Ideal.

Comment: Hi @GaryHengeveld , put the selected item in the position of the `ComboBox` in the popup layer, which is the behavior of `ComboBox` in most cases. When the list has been scrolled to the bottom (or top), because the remaining items are limited, the selected item will not appear in the "middle position."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution to this the simplest solution I found was to set the RotateTransform angle of the view box to .0001. While I'm not entirely sure why it works, It does work.

Here Is the Style I created to fix it.

```
   <!--#region ViewBox Style to repair pointer misalignment-->
    <Style x:Key="ViewBoxPointerMisalignmentFix" TargetType="Viewbox">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle=".0001" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```